# How to protect this SQL in a PHP from SQL Injection?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Can someone give me a little help with this? i have three PHP SQL querys, and i have to protect from SQL Injection. I am searching on google but i think is too hard for me, because it's combinated with PHP and i dont know munch about PHP and lees about SQL

if someone can give me the code protected I'll be grateful

the code:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user where email= '".$_REQUEST['email']."'",$link );

$q=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET mobilePhone='".$_REQUEST['mobilePhone']."', fullName='".$_REQUEST['fullName']."' WHERE email='".$_REQUEST['email']."'",$link );

$q=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET mobilePhone='".$_REQUEST['mobilePhone']."' , fullName='".$_REQUEST['fullName']."', password='".$_REQUEST['password']."'  WHERE email='".$_REQUEST['email']."'",$link );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simple way would be to wrap each of the `$_REQUEST` vars in [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)...

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user 
    where email= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email'])."'",$link );
```

The better way would be to use prepared queries.  There are plenty of tutorials available on how to do it, so I'll leave that to you...

Answer (score 2):

The least you can do to prevent SQL injection is to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function before any variables that go into your queries.

The best you can do is to [use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection.

> The parameters to prepared statements
>   don't need to be quoted; the driver
>   automatically handles this. **If an
>   application exclusively uses prepared
>   statements, the developer can be sure
>   that no SQL injection will occur
>   (however, if other portions of the
>   query are being built up with
>   unescaped input, SQL injection is
>   still possible).**

**Suggestion:**

To be further on safer side, you should always use proper array eg `$_POST` or `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST` for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PHP's mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: prepared statements with placeholders are a much better practice.

Comment: +1 as while prepared statements are better, that doesn't mean using `mres` is a **bad** thing.  You're still safe...

Comment: @ircmaxell nothing bad in mres, if used wisely. And a fool (loke OP) would fail with prepared. A brain is the only necessary thing, and the rest is optional.